# UglifyJS convert unicode diacritics to ASCII

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, diacritics, uglifyjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I'm using grunt-contrib-uglify with version `^2.0.0` to compress JavaScript files. My code contains diacritics, e.g.:

```
var diacritics = ["aÀÁÂ"];
```

Now, when I put this into the [Closure Compiler](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home#code%3Dvar%2520diacritics%2520%253D%2520%255B%2522a%25C3%2580%25C3%2581%25C3%2582%2522%255D%253B) I get the following result:

```
var diacritics=["a\u00c0\u00c1\u00c2"];
```

I'd like to have the same when using UglifyJS. I've already tried using options like `ascii`, `ascii_only`, `ASCIIOnly` but nothing worked.

Is there any option to get the expected result?

Comment: Why? Isn't the Closure Compiler doing something completely unnecessary and reducing readability?

Comment: No, but UglifyJS is part of my workflow and I'd like to keep it.

Comment: I believe that @TomBlodget means that such encoding is unneeded, and it's unclear why you need it instead of keeping unicode strings as is. (By the way, I would like to _disable_ such encoding in Closure Compiler if that was possible.)

Comment: With closure-compiler, you can disable such encoding with the `--charset=UTF-8` flag. By default, input is UTF-8 and output is US ASCII.

Comment: @Marat Tanalin Well, I have several users with non-UTF8 servers having issues serving my files containing diacritics too. I'd like to encode them to make sure everything works as expected regardless how a server is configured.

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth Thanks for the useful tip. It works with the standalone Java version of Closure Compiler, but looks like does _not_ work with the [online service](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) — I’ve tried to add `// @charset UTF-8` to the header-comment block, but it had no effect.

Comment: @dude Indeed, for non-UTF-8-capable server side, such escaping could be inevitably needed. But fortunately, such cases are currently very rare, and UTF-8 is the default for the modern web, so the escaping is unneeded in most cases.

Comment: Yes, but this question is about these rare cases ;-)